# How to plan a script to be executed at session end inside a powershell script?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am writing a login script in Powershell which install a amount of printers, depending on the user currently loggin into Windows 7. I would like this user to remove the printers it have installed as soon as they are not required anymore, so as soon as this user log out.

How can I plan a script which will be executed as soon as the current sessions ends in Powershell?

Thank for your time.

PS: I cannot use AD for installing printers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either set up a scheduled task that is triggered by Event 4634 ("logon session destroyed") in the Security Event Log, or you can assign a logoff script through the Local Group Policy Editor:

[image]

Logoff script details are saved in a key in the users registry hive:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-<SIDofUserInQuestion>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Logoff\<ExecutionOrder>\0
```

You would have to update this user-specific key for each user if you want to automate the assignment of these logoff scripts to

Answer (score 1):

When you say you can't use AD, do you mean that you don't want to manage printers through Group Policy *Preferences*, or that you can't use Group Policy *at all* for this task? I ask because the easiest and probably most maintainable way to run a script when users log off is to add the script as a Logoff Script using Group Policy.

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753583.aspx) describes how to set logon and logoff scripts using Group Policy. There will be a few differences since you're adding a PowerShell script. The process will look something like this:

1. Open Group Policy Editor.

   - If the computers that you want to set the logoff scripts on aren't joined to a domain, just run **gpedit.msc** from the Run dialog or a Command Prompt.
   - If you do have a domain, open Group Policy Management (**gpmc.msc**) either on one of your domain servers, or better yet, using Microsoft's [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731209.aspx) on a domain-joined workstation. Then you'll navigate to the organizational unit that you want to set the policy in, and create a new policy or edit an existing one.
2. Once you're in Group Policy Editor, navigate to **User Configuration\Windows Settings\Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**.
3. Select the **PowerShell Scripts** tab.
4. Add your script that removes printers.